# Orthogonal Matrix Eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Verify that if P is an orthogonal matrix and x = Py then $y^Ty = x^Tx$.
Let A be a real symmetric n × n matrix. Then we know that there exists a real orthogonal matrix P such that $P^TAP$ is diagonal. By using the transformation x = Py, or otherwise, prove that for every x ∈$R_n$,

$$mx^Tx ≤ x^TAx ≤ Mx^Tx$$
where m and M are the smallest and greatest eigenvalues of A respectively. For which x is it true that $x^TAx = Mx^Tx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x  = Py$
If $P$ is orthogonal

$x^Tx = $$(Py)^T(Py)\\
y^TP^TPy\\
y^Ty$

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix then there exists an orthogonal $P$ such that: $A = P^TDP$

$x^TAx = (Px)^TD(Px)\\
y = Px\\
x^TAx = y^TDy$

$y^TDy = \sum \lambda_iy_i^2$

Since each $y_i^2 >0$

$\lambda_{min}\sum y_i^2\le \sum \lambda_iy_i^2\le \lambda_{max}\sum y_i^2$

$\lambda_{min}y^Ty \le y^TDy \le \lambda_{max}y^Ty\\
\lambda_{min}y^Ty \le x^TAx \le \lambda_{max}y^Ty$